# Why are my Li-ion cells rattling?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I have some ICR18650-22F cells from Samsung which I salvaged from a laptop battery. The weird thing is that a few of them are rattling when I shake them. It sounds like there is a metal ball inside of them.

I think it is a bad sign that the cells are rattling but the performance of them is the same as the performance of the non-rattling ones.

They are working just like new cells would so my questions are:

Why are some of the cells rattling?

Can I still use these cells without any problems?

Comment: After salvaging some 5000 cells from (dead) battery packs, rattling cells go in the junk bin to be disposed of properly. Uncommon, but it happens. I don't know exactly what is rattling though, so this isn't an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s the center rod in the middle of the “jellyroll” that has broken loose from the negative terminal. It was a thing with older Samsung 35E cells, I had a ton that did that. TECHNICALLY, it isn’t anything super dangerous as it’s not really possible for the rod, which is surrounded by material, to move around so much so to puncture anything internally and cause a fire. HOWEVER it’s not like you need this one specific cell to run something super essential, so considering you’re collecting cells I’d just recycle it for peace of mind and safety. [Source](https://old.reddit.com/r/batteries/comments/ynp7m7/my_18650_battery_is_clicking_when_shaken/ivbjxw7/)